# MVC implementation in (pure) C

Tags: c, model-view-controller, sdl

Let's say I would like to write a graphic application in C (using SDL), following a Model-View-Controller design.

My problem is that I have to load graphic resources (like images) and *I would like them to be stored in the view part, and only in this part.*
Hence, I want the controller and the model part to know nothing about these resources, but I want them known to the functions of the view when they are called.

Should I use a global struct with pointers to these resources, known to everyone, or a static struct, or something else? What do you think would be good solution to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

All functions that need access to those variables, could be grouped to a single source and the respective shared vars could be declares as static. They will be "global" but only to code in that source file. Functions not having to know about those variables, would be placed into different source file.